# Can’t get into my ipad

Tags: ipad

My sister gave me her extra iPad from several years ago and I can’t get into it.  Problem is that she bought it for a dog shelter to use and the guy there had his own ID and password and she had hers. When she got it back from the shelter I deleted her info but cannot use the iPad because his info is in it and he’s long moved away and cannot contact him to have him delete it remotely. Is there any way to be able to use this iPad again?